# Get mac addresses of in range wifi routers

Tags: java, android, wifi

I have the following code which lists the ssid and rssi of all networks in range:

```java
    public static void getWIFI(Context context) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        String macAddr = wifiInf.getMacAddress();

        final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();

        if (results != null) {
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

            for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
                float rssi = results.get(i).level;
                buf.append(ssid + ": " + rssi + "\n");
            }

            Log.i("W-LAN", buf.toString());
        }
    }
```

However calling `wifiInf.getMacAddress();` always returns the same generic address. I've read that this worked until Android 6.0. All solutions I could find list only your own mac address and not of all networks. Is there a way to get the mac address and rssi of all networks in range?

Comment: you will have to connect to the network to ge tthe address I think

Comment: It should be possible without, there are apps that can do it. Like WiFi Monitor.

Comment: Is there no solution to this? How do apps like WiFi Monitor (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.signalmonitoring.wifimonitoring&hl=de) get the mac address?

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (ScanResult scanResult : scanResults) {
    Map hashMap = new HashMap();
    hashMap.put("wifiMac", scanResult.BSSID == null ? "" : scanResult.BSSID);
    hashMap.put("ssid", scanResult.SSID);
    hashMap.put("rssi", scanResult.level);
    arrayList.add(hashMap);
}
```

you can try this bro

Comment: Project is finished for some time now, but thanks for the answer anyway :D. Don't remeber how I solved it, I will look it up and post it too.